# Calculating number of unique values with a zero in the adjacent column

Tags: r, dataframe

Although there may be (what I hope), a simple solution to this, I cannot seem to arrive at one. With a series of paired columns, I want to calculate the number of unique values in every even numbered column (df2, df4, df6) that possesses a zero in its corresponding column on the left (df1,df3,df5).

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:1000, 36*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=1))
df2 <- as.data.frame(rep(1:12, each=30))
df3 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:500, 36*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=1))
df4 <- as.data.frame(c(rep(5:12, each=30),rep(1:4, each=30)))
df5 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:200, 36*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=1))
df6 <- as.data.frame(c(rep(8:12, each=30),rep(1:7, each=30)))
Example <- cbind(df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,df6)
```

I can reduce the number of rows to those possessing zeros through this function, I'm not sure if this is a necessary step though.

```
Example <- as.data.frame(Example[which(apply(Example[-1], 1, function(x) min(x) <= 0)),])
```

So as an example, if I had the data frame...

```
df1 df2 df3 df4 df5 df6 
 1   1   9   1   0   1
 0   2   5   2   0   2
```

... I would want the output to be

```
df2  df4  df6 
 1    0    2
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is not reproducible: `object 'ntest' not found`.

Comment: Your sample output appears to be faulty, because `df2` has _2_ unique values 1 and 2.

Comment: Apologies I have edited the code, I coped and pasted the final line in by accident. df2 does have 2 unique values, but only 1 unique value that possesses a 0 in the adjacent column to the left. I hope this is more clear now sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your data.frame is `df`, you can do:

```
colSums(df[, seq(ncol(df))%%2==1]==0)
#df1 df3 df5 
#  1   0   2
```

basically, instead of searching for the adjacent 0 value, it counts the 0 in the odd columns but the result is the same.

***If you really want the column names to correspond to the even columns, you can do:***

```
w_odd <- seq(ncol(df))%%2==1
setNames(colSums(df[, w_odd]==0), colnames(df)[!w_odd])
#df2 df4 df6 
#  1   0   2
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(df1 = c(1L, 0L), df2 = 1:2, df3 = c(9L, 5L), df4 = 1:2, 
    df5 = c(0L, 0L), df6 = 1:2), .Names = c("df1", "df2", "df3", 
"df4", "df5", "df6"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```